# getting these error messages everytime on apt install upgrade or installing applications on 22.04 LTS

Tags: apt, kernel, dpkg, initramfs

```
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.140ubuntu13.4) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Setting up linux-firmware (20220329.git681281e4-0ubuntu3.17) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.19.0-50-generic
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/plymouth failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-5.19.0-50-generic with 1.
dpkg: error processing package linux-firmware (--configure):
 installed linux-firmware package post-installation script subprocess returned
 error exit status 1
Setting up util-linux-locales (2.37.2-4ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1) ...
Processing triggers for mailcap (3.70+nmu1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.140ubuntu13.4) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.19.0-50-generic
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/plymouth failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-5.19.0-50-generic with 1.
dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 installed initramfs-tools package post-installation script subprocess returne
d error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-firmware
 initramfs-tools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```